# I want to start thread from my service, so that the operations do not run in the main thread of android

Tags: java, android, android-service

I used the following code and its working, but want to know that is it really an efficient way to do it?

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service 
{
    Runner runner;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
          return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
          super.onCreate();
          Toast.makeText(this,"Service created ...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
          super.onDestroy(); 
          Toast.makeText(this, "Service destroyed ...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          //stopSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId){

        try{
            Toast.makeText(this,"Service started ...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            runner = new Runner();
            runner.start();

        }catch(Exception localException){}
        return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }    
}

public class Runner extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run(){
        try
        {
            //code to run actual task
        }catch(Exception localException){}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of way how to do some background processing in android. 
There are also some like

- [Handlers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html),
- [AsyncTasks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)
- Service
- and maybye some that I don't know already

Proper approach to do async stuff in android depedns on the kind of work to do. If you do some stuff constantly you simple create service as you did.

If you want to run sth smaller one shot taks you can create Handler or AsyncTask.

Like I said it depends on the sort of work that you would like to do in background.

Comment: my work is continuous and will be running for long time. So as per you  the way i did is most suitable. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Yes I think that is the best way.

Comment: So if my answer is suitable for you you can simply upvote it and accept. Thanks in advance.